# Internal Navigation in PDF using syncfusion package in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, linker, syncfusion

I've been working on an App in flutter to generate a PDF file containing a list of indexes and its corresponding content portions. What I want to achieve is to navigate to the specific contents while clicking on the index elements. I followed the documentation here: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-hyperlinks, but it didn't solved my issue.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';   
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'package:lorem_ipsum/lorem_ipsum.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart';

reportView(context) async {
  PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
  PdfPage firstPage = document.pages.add();
  PdfPage secondPage = document.pages.add();
     

  Rect firstRectangle = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 150, 100);
  Rect secondRectangle = Rect.fromLTWH(170, 100, 0, 0);

  //Contents for first page
  firstPage.graphics.drawString(
      'Hello World!!!', PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 27),
      brush: PdfBrushes.darkBlue, bounds: firstRectangle);

  //Contents for second page
  secondPage.graphics.drawString(
      loremIpsum(words: 60, paragraphs: 3, initWithLorem: true), PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 27),
      brush: PdfBrushes.darkBlue,bounds: secondRectangle);


  //Creating the first annotation
  PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation firstAnnotation = new PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation(firstRectangle,PdfDestination(secondPage));
  firstPage.annotations.add(firstAnnotation);

  //Creating the second annotation
  PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation secondAnnotation = new PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation(secondRectangle,PdfDestination(firstPage));
  firstPage.annotations.add(secondAnnotation);

  //Saving the document
  final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  final String path = '$dir/App_' + '.pdf';
  await File(path).writeAsBytes(document.save());
  print(path);
  Share.shareFiles([path]);
  document.dispose();
}
```

I can't seem to find any clickable points in my final generated PDF. What am i doing wrong here? Is there something else i have to do for the proper working of internal navigation?

Answer (score 0):

At present we do not have support draw appearance for document link annotation. So we suggest you to draw the clickable points using page graphics as below.

```
//Create PDF document
PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
//Add pages
PdfPage firstPage = document.pages.add();
PdfPage secondPage = document.pages.add();

Rect firstRectangle = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 150, 100);
Rect secondRectangle = Rect.fromLTWH(170, 100, 150, 100);

//Contents for first page
firstPage.graphics.drawString(
    'Hello World!!!', PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 27),
    brush: PdfBrushes.darkBlue, bounds: firstRectangle);

//Contents for second page
secondPage.graphics.drawString(
    'second page text', PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 27),
    brush: PdfBrushes.darkBlue, bounds: secondRectangle);

//Creating the first annotation
PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation firstAnnotation = new PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation(
    firstRectangle, PdfDestination(secondPage));
firstPage.annotations.add(firstAnnotation);

//Draw appearance.
firstPage.graphics
    .drawRectangle(bounds: firstRectangle, pen: PdfPens.black);

//Creating the second annotation
PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation secondAnnotation = new PdfDocumentLinkAnnotation(
    secondRectangle, PdfDestination(firstPage));
firstPage.annotations.add(secondAnnotation);

//Draw appearance.
firstPage.graphics
    .drawRectangle(bounds: secondRectangle, pen: PdfPens.black);

//Saving the document
final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
final String path = '$dir/App_' + '.pdf';
await File(path).writeAsBytes(document.save());
print(path);
Share.shareFiles([path]);
document.dispose();
```

Also the second document link annotation added with the width and height of **0,0**, due to that the annotation is not configured properly. We have changed the bounds too for the above code.